# How to get the count of test suites run in TestNG?

Tags: testng

Hi All am trying to customize the testng execution results output in console using `TestNG Listeners`, i have got different test suites under parent test suite, am stuck in getting the count of testsuites run at the time of test execution.Any suggestions??

Comment: Do you want it at the end of all suite execution or while things are running?

Comment: at the end of the execution

Comment: At the end of entire execution, but the testng report itself would give it right?  else the ISuiteListener as suggested below doesn;t help?

Comment: At the end of Execution TestNG doesnot give info abt no. of suites executed.. neways thanks for the response.. currently ll go with the below approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options to track at runtime ...
You can implement ISuiteListener and increment the counts of suites started.  You can maintain a counter for the suites completed as well and output to your console.
Say in onstart, increment the global counter for started suites and in onfinish, increment the finished ones.  You can maintain a running suites counter as well.